# SIM800L always returns +CREG: 0,2

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using a SIM800L module, and I am checking the status of my network with the `AT+CREG?` command.

However, it always returns the same 0,2:

```
0 -> disable network registration unsolicited result code

2 -> not registered, but ME is currently searching a new operator to register to
```

How do I activate 2G or 3G network?

Answer (score 1):

- It can take a while to register - sometimes several minutes. Have you left it after power-up for enough time?
- If your operator has no signal in your area it will never register. National roaming is normally disabled. If you have national roaming available you will have to manually connect to another operator.
- Check that your modem can see your operator with `AT+COPS=?`

Comment: I can see the operators list with command AT+COPS=?. But I can't register on them!

Comment: Do you need a pin for the simcard?

Comment: Not, I have pin. I can't connect to a network!